# Android Webviews load Javascript with 1mb?

Tags: android, webview

I started playing with Xamarin and Android development. I wanted to program a WebView app, sadly I get an error when loading a JS with about 1mb.

This is my code so far:

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    private WebView web_view;

    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

        web_view = FindViewById<WebView> (Resource.Id.webview);
        web_view.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
        web_view.SetWebChromeClient (new WebChromeClient ());
        web_view.LoadUrl ("https://my-domain.com/my-js.js");

    }
}
```

And this is the error I get:
"Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Is my assumption correct that the JS file is to big? Is there a workaround for the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed my problem yesterday. I had to enable the dom storage:

```
web_view.Settings.DomStorageEnabled = true;
```

This line of code fixed the problem and the Javascript had no problem to load.